# How to parse regular (not newline delimited) json with Apache Beam and Jackson?

Tags: java, json, jackson, apache-beam

I am trying to learn how to parse JSON data to CSV format with Apache Beam and Jackson. I am starting with a very simple JSON file:

```
{
    "firstName": "John", 
    "lastName": "Smith", 
    "isAlive": true, 
    "age": 27
}
```

I have a corresponding POJO structure:

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;

@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Person implements Serializable {
    
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private int age;

    public Person() {}

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

   ... getters & setters ...
```

However, when I try to parse this json, I get a formatting error:

```
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unexpected close marker '}': expected ']' (for root starting at [Source: }; line: 1, column: 0])
 at [Source: }; line: 1, column: 2]
```

Which I solved by converting the json to this format:

```
{"firstName": "John", "lastName": "Smith", "isAlive": true, "age": 27}
```

My eventual need is to deal with plain old json. Is there a way to do so, and if so, how?

The Apache Beam code is this simple pipeline:

```
public class DataToModel {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        PipelineOptions options = PipelineOptionsFactory.create();
        options.setRunner(DirectRunner.class);
        Pipeline p = Pipeline.create(options);

        // read data from json
        PCollection<String>  json = p.apply(TextIO.read().from("src/main/resources/test.json"));
        PCollection<Person> person = json
            .apply(ParseJsons.of(Person.class))
            .setCoder(SerializableCoder.of(Person.class));

        // parse json
        PCollection<String> names = person.apply(MapElements
            .into(TypeDescriptors.strings())
            .via(Person::getFirstName)
        );

        // write information to file.
        names.apply(TextIO.write().to("src/main/resources/test_out"));

        p.run().waitUntilFinish();

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are using `TextIO.read()` to read from the json files. TextIO reads each line of a text file into a separate element, so a multi-line JSON object gets split into multiple elements. That means your parse function attempts to parse JSON strings such as `};`. That also explains why it succeeds if you format your object entirely on one line.

There are two approaches you could go with depending on what's available to you.

1. If possible with your JSON files, you could use the [`withDelimiter`](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.33.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/TextIO.Read.html#withDelimiter-byte:A-) method to use a custom delimeter aside from the default newline. However this is pretty brittle and requires your files to be formatted very specifically.
2. You could switch from TextIO to [FileIO](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.33.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/FileIO.html), and read each file into a single string to send to `ParseJsons`. This is slightly more work but far less brittle, and is what I would recommend.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [org.json](https://github.com/stleary/JSON-java) library; it is easy to use.

Just remember (while casting or using methods like getJSONObject and getJSONArray) that in JSON notation
[ … ] represents an array, so library will parse it to JSONArray
{ … } represents an object, so library will parse it to JSONObject

You can see more [information](https://github.com/stleary/JSON-java) about.

You can see a simple example below:

JSON file:

```
{
       "pageInfo": {
             "pageName": "abc",
             "pagePic": "http://example.com/content.jpg"
        },
        "posts": [
             {
                  "post_id": "123456789012_123456789012",
                  "actor_id": "1234567890",
                  "picOfPersonWhoPosted": "http://example.com/photo.jpg",
                  "nameOfPersonWhoPosted": "Jane Doe",
                  "message": "Sounds cool. Can't wait to see it!",
                  "likesCount": "2",
                  "comments": [],
                  "timeOfPost": "1234567890"
             }
        ]
    }
```

Code example:

```
import org.json.*;

String jsonString = ... ; //assign your JSON String here
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(jsonString);
String pageName = obj.getJSONObject("pageInfo").getString("pageName");

JSONArray arr = obj.getJSONArray("posts"); // notice that `"posts": [...]`
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length(); i++)
{
    String post_id = arr.getJSONObject(i).getString("post_id");
    ......
}
```

You may find more examples here: [Parse JSON in Java](http://theoryapp.com/parse-json-in-java/).

[Downloadable jar](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json).